# Play Audio from url inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

How to play audio file when user click on play button inside UITableViewCell? like playing audio from Whatsapp chat message, any open source library could save my time?

Answer (score 4):

I have created same module which you want. I have designed and created custom table view cell to load music from my bundle in table view.

Created respective required variable for same.

```
// Music Related Variables
var musicKeyboardView                           : UIView!
var arrMusics                                   : [String] = []
var previousAudioSelectedIndexPath              : IndexPath!
var audioPlayer                                 : AVAudioPlayer?
```

As per arrMusics you can load path of your music. I'm loading it from bundle as follows:

```
func fetchMusicFromResource() {

    // First remove all music data from array
    // This code is required because every time switching keyboard will duplicate data.
    self.arrMusics.removeAll()

    // Fetch all the files paths from CustomKeyboard Target.
    // This code return array of string which contains paths for every resource inside CustomKeyboard.
    if let files = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: Bundle.main.bundlePath) {

        // Take single file and check if it contains "mp3" string, then add to arrMusic.
        // Write this code if you know there are mp3 extension for song.
        // We know that resource contains mp3 for music file, so this code will work fine.
        // You need to change if this is dynamic, means music file with other extensions.
        // Make sure video file name not contains mp3 text, otherwise it will not work or may be crash the app.
        // If you will use music library songs, then you don't need this code.
        for file in files {
            if file.contains("mp3") {
                self.arrMusics.append(file)
            }
        }

        // Check if arrMusics contains elements more then 0 then, hide the label and show the table,
        // otherwise show label and hide table
        if self.arrMusics.count > 0 {
            self.tblMusic.isHidden = false
            self.lblEmptyMusic.isHidden = true
        } else {
            self.tblMusic.isHidden = true
            self.lblEmptyMusic.isHidden = false
        }

        // Set table rowHeight and estimatedRowHeight as TableViewAutomaticDimension and reload table.
        self.tblMusic.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tblMusic.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tblMusic.reloadData()
    }
}
```

So in cellForRowAt indexPath method I'm adding target for playButton as follows:

```
musicCell.btnPlay.tag = indexPath.row * 10
cell.btnPlay.addTarget(self, action: #selector(musicPlayButtonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

When click on play button it will fire musicPlayButtonClicked(sender:) method which contains following code to play music.

```
@IBAction func musicPlayButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {

    // Take the row by sender.tag / 10.
    // Previous we set tag of play button with indexPath.row * 10
    // So here we are deviding and get original row index and create indexPath for selected row.
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag / 10, section: 0)

    // This code check if previousAudioSelectedIndexPath not nil,
    // then execute code inside if block
    if previousAudioSelectedIndexPath != nil {

        // This code check indexPath is equal to previousAudioSelectedIndexPath.
        if (indexPath == previousAudioSelectedIndexPath) {

            // Set button's selected propery to true.
            sender.isSelected = false

            // Set previousAudioSelectedIndexPath to nil.
            previousAudioSelectedIndexPath = nil

            // Call method to play music for selected index.
            self.playMusicAt(index: sender.tag)

        } else {

            // Create cell for previousAudioSelectedIndexPath.
            let previousSelectedCell = self.tblMusic.cellForRow(at: previousAudioSelectedIndexPath)

            // Take the previousButton selected from previousSelectedCell and Set previousButton's isSelected property to false.
            if let previousButton = previousSelectedCell!.contentView.subviews[1] as? UIButton {
                previousButton.isSelected = false
            }

            // Set button's selected propery to true for current selected button.
            sender.isSelected = true

            // Assign current selected indexPath to previous selected indexPath.
            previousAudioSelectedIndexPath = indexPath

            // Call method to play music for selected index.
            self.playMusicAt(index: sender.tag)
        }

    } else {

        // If current button is selected then stop playing music,
        // Otherwise execute code of else block to play music.
        if sender.isSelected {

            // This code will stop the music for selected row.
            sender.isSelected = false
            previousAudioSelectedIndexPath = nil
            self.playMusicAt(index: sender.tag)

        } else {

            // This code will start to play the music for selected row.
            sender.isSelected = true
            previousAudioSelectedIndexPath = indexPath
            self.playMusicAt(index: sender.tag)
        }
    }
}
```

This code will used to get cell button and set respective image related to play/pause on it.

Then there are one more method which will created to play song at path getting from array. Look at following method.

```
func playMusicAt(index: Int) {

    // This will check is audioPlayer is not nil and audioPlayer is already playing,
    // Then first pause audioPlayer and remove it from memory.
    if audioPlayer != nil, (audioPlayer?.isPlaying)! {
        audioPlayer?.pause()
        audioPlayer = nil
    }

    // This line of code check previousAudioSelectedIndexPath is not nil,
    // then execute code with if block.
    if previousAudioSelectedIndexPath != nil {

        // This code copy song name from selected index
        let songName = self.arrMusics[index / 10].components(separatedBy: ".")

        // Create source path of song name with extension.
        // If it's failed to create url path,
        // then return from this line of code and stop to execute next lines of code.
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: songName[0], withExtension: "mp3") else { return }

        do {

            // This will start the AVAudioSession for AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback.
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)

            // This code will active AVAudioSession.
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            /* The following line is required for the player to work on iOS 11. Change the file type accordingly*/
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)

            /* iOS 10 and earlier require the following line:
             player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeMP3Layer3) */

            // Create new audio player,
            // if audio plyer is failed to create,
            // then return from this line of code and stop to execute next lines of code.
            guard let audioPlayer = audioPlayer else { return }

            // This code start playing song
            audioPlayer.play()

        } catch let error {
            // If audio session failed to start or AVAudioPlayer failed to initialised then throw the error.
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this code will help you.